# Proportional to 2 Separate Variables vs. Proportional to Product of 2 Variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've commonly seen the following in physics and math textbooks, but never understood how it is mathematically deduced:

$A \propto B$ $\space$ and $\space$ $A \propto C \space\space\space \implies \space\space\space A \propto BC.$

Could someone walk me through how this is done? This has been bothering me for a while now.

**Update**: [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=DlwYC90SLEcC&pg=PA243&lpg=PA243&dq=%22Varies+as+their+Product%22&source=bl&ots=EHztg0L-vL&sig=OzV81ecJm9HWC_z_iXzl5LSyQPw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OVwbUI2yIrCN6QH28oDQDw&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22Varies%20as%20their%20Product%22&f=false)'s something I found that explains how this works. (Page 387; "Proof" section). Still, this proof takes the two statements *one after the other*. The author uses $x \propto y$ when $z$ is constant, and then takes care of $x \propto z$ when $y$ is constant, where it left off from the first (going from $x$ to $x'$ and then $x_1$). Is this the only way it can be done?

Comment: Re: "Is this the only way it can be done?" Given that the premise $A\propto B$ tells you how $A$ changes with $B$ while *holding everything else constant*, and the same goes for $A\propto C$, I don't think you can get anywhere without only changing one of $B$ and $C$ at a time. If you like, you can prove that it doesn't matter whether you do $B$ and then $C$, or $C$ and then $B$, or $B$ halfway then $C$ then $B$ the rest of the way, or any other path, you will always get the same answer.

Comment: @Rahul Narain - So in other words the constants of proportionality for each statement hold the "opposite" variable as a factor, correct? (ie. $A = m(C)B$ and $A = n(B)C$)

Comment: Pretty much, yes. The constant of proportionality with respect to $B$ is a function of $C$, and vice versa, as you wrote.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for clearing this up for me! :-) You should answer my question so I can +1 you and mark it as the answer haha

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $f(a,b)$ being directly proportional to $a$ and $b$ separately imply that $f(a,b)$ is directly proportional to $ab?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322004/does-fa-b-being-directly-proportional-to-a-and-b-separately-imply-that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting my comments into an answer: If we say $A \propto B$ when $A$ also depends on other things, what we mean is that holding everything else fixed, $A$ increases linearly with $B$. So $A = mB$ for some $m$, and $m$ is constant relative to $B$, but may vary depending on the other things.

This is getting a bit wooly, so let's be more explicit. Let's say $A$ is a function of $B$, $C$, and $D$. Then $A \propto B$ means $A(B,C,D) = f(C,D)\cdot B$ for some function $f$. On the other hand, if $A \propto C$, then $A(B,C,D) = g(B,D)\cdot C$ for some other $g$. When you can put those together and go through some algebra, you'll find that $A(B,C,D) = h(D)\cdot BC$, that is, $A \propto BC$.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a simpler explicit proof.

Let A be k when B and C are 1: $(k,1,1)$

Then, if we keep C constant and multiply B by $b$, A goes up by b: $(kb,b,1)$.

If we keep B constant now and scale C by $c$, A goes up by $c$: $(kbc,b,c)$

Thus, $a=kbc$ in general, so A is proportional to BC.

Answer (score 0):

This is based off of wikipedia's article on Combined Gas Law and some of my own inputs.

We have A $\propto B$ and $A \propto C$.

Thus we get (noting that proportionality is symmetric),
$$B = k_C(C)A$$
$$C = k_B(B)A$$

where $k_C$ is a function of only C and $k_B$ that of B.
The proportionality constants could depend on various other things, but for now, we focus on A, B, C only as all other parameters are considered fixed. Then we get 
$$A = \frac{B}{k_C(C)} = \frac{C}{k_B(B)}$$
$$\Rightarrow Bk_B(B) = Ck_C(C)$$

Now in the previous line, **LHS is a function of B only, RHS is a function of C only!!!!** Thus both are independent of B and C and therefore must be a constant. Call this constant K.

Then $k_B(B) = \frac{K}{B}$. Substitute back to get 
$$BC = KA$$ or 
$$BC \propto A$$
$\blacksquare$