# Combined Proportions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been taking an ODE course and a word problem involved some quantity $x$ being directly and inversely proportional to others. I recall it said something like: $x$ is directly proportional to $y$ and $z$ and inversely proportional to $t$. I didn't really paused and ponder that the appropriate formula for $x$ was $x = k\dfrac{yz}{t}$, for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$. I assumed that this proportionality took place whenever the other variables were held constant.

However, today I wanted to, step by step, get to the formula given above. Writing all definitions: $x = a\cdot y$, $x = b \cdot z$ and $x = \dfrac{c}{t}$. But I wasn't able to get to that formula!

I'm stuck. Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

Comment: Interestingly, this is something that seems to be ignored in textbooks despite being not entirely trivial (which I initially expected), at least I don't recall having seen it discussed. See [Proportional to 2 Separate Variables vs. Proportional to Product of 2 Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174948/13130) **AND** [If A $\propto$ B and A $\propto$ C while keeping each other constant, then why is A $\propto$ BC?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/256918/13130) **AND** [Proportion of one varaiable to two different variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4166408/13130).

Comment: @UriToti The theorem holds **under the assumption that $y,z,t$ are independent of one another**. My proof of the theorem is at [Does $A$ being directly proportional to both $B$ and $C$ imply that $A$ is jointly proportional to $BC?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322004/does-fa-b-being-directly-proportional-to-a-and-b-separately-imply-that).